# Best way to run celerymon in the background

Tags: django, celery, nagios

Since I am a Django newbie, I need to ask what would be the best way to start [celerymon](https://github.com/celery/celerymon/) and keep it running in the background?

I use it for monitoring Celery with Nagios.

This is how I start it now:

```
./manage.py celerymon --detach --settings=settings.jacob
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [common solution](http://www.google.com/search?q=supervisor%20django) to manage processes in Django is [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/).

Shouldn't be too hard to extend this example: [How to keep Celery running with Supervisor?](http://thomassileo.com/blog/2012/08/20/how-to-keep-celery-running-with-supervisor/)